# F# CsvTypeProvider - mapping function from inferred types

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I am using the CsvTypeProvider to map data from CSV files into my own data structures. This works splendidly, except for that I have to repeat the mapping function every time:

```
type GamesFile = CsvProvider<"./data/15.csv">
let games15 = GamesFile.Load("./data/15.csv").Rows |> Seq.map ( fun c -> { Division = c.Div; Date = c.Date; HomeScore = c.HomeScore; AwayScore = c.AwayScore })
let games16 = GamesFile.Load("./data/16.csv").Rows |> Seq.map ( fun c -> { Division = c.Div; Date = c.Date; HomeScore = c.HomeScore; AwayScore = c.AwayScore })
```

When I try moving it to a function, I am told that "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

This makes sense, but how can I tell a mapping function what type it is when the type is inferred from the contents of the CSV? How is this normally solved?

Comment: Just hover on `c` in your IDE, it will show you the type. It will also clear your confusion about where the type is defined.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin To be fair, the tootip for type providers is a bit confusing, because it ignores the type alias..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type provider generates a type representing the row and it exposes it as a nested type of the main provided type - in your case aliased as `GamesFile`.

This is not entirely obvious, because the editors will show tooltip with something like
`CsvFile<...>.Row` so it does not show the name of the alias, but it suggests `Row` is a nested type. To use the type in your code, you can just write `GamesFile.Row`, so you need something like this:

```
type GamesFile = CsvProvider<"./data/15.csv">

let mapRows (rows:seq<GamesFile.Row>) = 
  rows |> Seq.map (fun c -> 
    { Division = c.Div; Date = c.Date; HomeScore = c.HomeScore; AwayScore = c.AwayScore })

let games15 = GamesFile.Load("./data/15.csv").Rows |> mapRows
let games16 = GamesFile.Load("./data/16.csv").Rows |> mapRows
```

Comment: Can you also write `CsvProvider<"./data/15.csv">.Row` instead of `GamesFile.Row`?

Comment: I believe you can, but it does not sound like a good idea to me :-)

Comment: Still, this would make the "just hover on it" solution at least workable, even if not very elegant.